# Union of data from all tables with name containing a substring

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have 500+ tables all containing a column called `COLUMNDATA`. The table names are like: `TABLE_FIRST, TABLE_SECOND, ... ,TABLE_FIVE_HUNDREDTH`. What I am trying to get is a column containing all the unique entries from `COLUMNDATA` across all of these tables. The problem is made a little more challenging because all tables in the DB contain this column, and I am not interested in data from the tables which aren't called `TABLE_NUMBER`.

I have tried various recipes including `UNION` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLE%'` but to no avail.

If anyone has an idea that would be great! Otherwise I'll just stick with the 1000 line script I've got already. For now I have a nasty but gets-the-job-done

`CREATE TABLE TAB_NAME
AS 
SELECT COLUMNDATA FROM TABLE_FIRST
UNION
SELECT COLUMNDATA FROM TABLE_SECOND
UNION . . .`

ad infinitum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a script but it doesn't have to be 1000 lines.

--make a table or global temporary table to put the results in

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_COLUMN_DATA
( PK_ID NUMBER(9),
  TABLE_SOURCE VARCHAR2(30),
  TEXT_CONTENT VARCHAR2(4000));
```

--add the primary key of PK_ID, are contents larger than 4000 characters?  use a CLOB

--create a trigger on the table if the PK_ID is null add a sequence value

```
DECLARE
v_text  VARCHAR2(4000);
CURSOR tab_col IS
Select TABLE_NAME from all_tab_cols
where COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMNDATA'
and table_name LIKE 'TABLE%'
--modify the cursor here to exclude any tables you dont want
--and table_name not in('xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx')
ORDER BY 1;
BEGIN
  FOR THE_TABS IN TAB_COL LOOP
    V_TEXT := 'INSERT INTO TEMP_COLUMN_DATA SELECT NULL,'
    || THE_TABS.TABLE_NAME 
    ||',' 
    || THE_TABS.TABLE_NAME 
    || '.COLUMNDATA ' 
    || ' from ' 
    || THE_TABS.TABLE_NAME 
    || ' order by 2';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_TEXT);
    EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE(v_text);
  END LOOP;
 END;
```

--then do a select distinct columndata from temp_column_data

Comment: Maybe I need to mention that there are other tables which contain the same column name which I am not interested in? It seems that this solution will grab data from any table containing `COLUMNDATA`, right?

Comment: @MelvynDrag see my edit

Comment: I edited the question. The column I am trying to grab is in nearly every table in the database. So, to write out a list of undesired table names doesn't solve the problem so much as transform it into an equally tedious one!

Comment: @MelvynDrag what is the characteristic of the tables you don't want?

Comment: There isn't any real unifying characteristic other than the fact that they have names which aren't like `TABLE_NUMBER`. I'm very surprised that this isn't a common SQL scripting task! I do this sort of thing regularly in bash.

Comment: Okay, this looks like just the trick - but could you double check the insides of the for loop? I get a couple of errors saying a) Wrong number of types of arguments in call to '||' and b) Identifier `EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE` must be declared. THANKS

Comment: @MelvynDrag There you go, my lesson is don't code from memory, run it through the compiler!